# getAll() method of Infinispan shows wrong hit miss count

Tags: jboss, infinispan, jboss-eap-6, infinispan-8

I have downloaded infinispan 7.2.5 version and created a simple server in a cluster mode. I have placed it in a jboss folder(locally) and started the server. I have created a simple client that puts the data into the cache and another client that gets the data from the cache in eclipse.

what I have observed is in a cluster mode when I fetch single value that is not present into the cache, using getAll() method, getHits method  give me 1 count (Ideally it should have been miss 1) also when I try to get a value which is already present into the cache, getHits method shows count as 2.

Also in a standalone environment when i fetched a single value from cache using getAll() method which is not present I get getMisses() method count as 1 (which is expected) but again in standalone mode also when I try to get a single value which is present in cache I get getHits method count as 2.

This is really confusing me as why this is happening. while other get() methods of infinispan behave in an expected way. This seems to happens only with getAll() method.

why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version? We've just released 9.2.0.Final

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://developer.jboss.org/message/980741?et=watches.email.thread#980741

Comment: There is an issue with distributed caches if the requested keys are part of different servers.
As long as the owners are less than the number of nodes the problem does not appear.

The getAll invocation may fail or return a wrong result.